# Which is better performance, String OR Array in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

**mappings**

```
"brandKeyword" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "norms" : false,
          "analyzer" : "nori_custom"}
```

**value example1**

```
["apple", "samsung", "lg"]
```

**value example2**

```
"apple samsung lg"
```

Which of the two values ​​examples shows better performance?

If one of them is faster, why?

Elasticsearch version: 7.2.0

data node : 30

coordinating node(for search) : 8

coordinating node(for index) : 4

master node: 3

ingest node: 1

main shards: 15

replicas: 3

shards per node: 2

average document count: 324,000,000

average request per second: 60

Comment: It's impossible to say, it depends on too many factors (number of documents, sizing of the nodes, number of client requests per sec, complexity of the queries, etc, etc, etc). Can you explain what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Val 
I am checking performance tuning elements to improve search performance.

Comment: Can you explain what makes you think that this part specifically hinders your performance?

Comment: @Val The two examples mentioned above give the same search results, but are just curious as to whether there are any performance differences.

Comment: @YunjinJang can you provide the value of `took` param in search response of both queries ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja right now I think the OP has a single query but he wants to run it on two different mapping strategies, hence my suggestion to create a second index and try the query on both

Comment: @Val I see, makes sense

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out is simply to try it out. Create two indexes with the same amount of documents and test your queries on each of them.

In your case, you can create the second index, simply be reindexing the existing one into a second one with an ingest pipeline that transforms your string into an array, like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/to-array
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "split": {
        "field": "brandKeyword",
        "separator": "\\s+" 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) your data into the second index:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest",
    "pipeline": "to-array"
  }
}
```

You now have two indexes, one with `brandKeyword` as a string and another one with `brandKeyword` as an array. You can test away and figure out which one performs better in your current environment.